# Integration server could not be started (bip2057)

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

We have a problem that reoccurred several times on our ibm integration bus (version 10.0.0.6)

An integration server crashed, and the following exception occured:

"BIP2057
Integration server  could not be started: integration node name ; UUID ; label ."

Any ideas?

update:
I've noticed that before this problem starts, there are errors on the log says: "Failed to allocate memory", sometimes with abends.
The server has lots of GB for RAM, and it seems that the IIB does not require even half of it.

Ideas?

Comment: Which fix pack are you at?  the forth number in the version.  They are up to 11 right now (10.0.0.11).

Comment: We are on fixpack 10.0.0.6

Comment: I would suggest you try with the latest fix pack and if still an issue open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: It's not that simple because I don't know if there's a way to simulate this problem before upgrading the IIB

Comment: @JoshMc added more details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there is multiple possible solution, but as already proposed, opening a PMR to IBM might be the best solution.

1) You can try to increase the execution group HeapSize (exemple below for 1Go, I would recommend you to try it up to 4 Go) :

```
gigs=$((1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024))
mqsichangeproperties $BROKERNAME -e $EGNAME -n jvmMaxHeapSize -o ComIbmJVMManager -v $gigs
```

2) Try to install the latest fixpack, as already suggested. Rollbacking the upgrade is really easy.

```
mqsisop $BROKERNAME
. /app/iib/iib-10.0.0.11/server/bin/mqsiprofile 
mqsistart $BROKERNAME ##Now running with 10.0.0.11
mqsisop $BROKERNAME
. /app/iib/iib-10.0.0.6/server/bin/mqsiprofile 
mqsistart $BROKERNAME ##Now running with 10.0.0.6
```

Note1: You have to unlog because profile repetition is not allowed, so you can't load profile for two different versions within the same session
Note2: on my side I am working on a issue starting from IIB 10.0.0.8, the PMR is ongoing for 8 month, and the issue is still present in IIB 10.0.0.11, which means I am still running with 10.0.0.7

3) Reproduce the issue with a new execution group to isolate the issue :

If you have multiple applications on your execution group, create one execution group per application, and deploy each application in the corresponding execution group. If one of your execution group refuse to start, I would review the application in it

I hope one of these will fix your problem